# Attempting to write hosts to a csv only if they are pingable in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a list of IP addresses.

I am trying to write all of the live IP addresses to a **csv** file, but I am not having any luck.

I'm able to print the live addresses to stdout, but cannot write them to a csv.

I have my csv reader/writer objects in 2 different functions (in case I wanted to import them later), but this did not work.

I then tried to place the both in one function but I am a bit confused on how I can get the live addresses from stdout to the csv file.

I understand I can remove the else statement.

Snippet of my code:

```
def readCsv():
    with open("random.csv", "r") as csvFile:
        csvReader = csv.reader(csvFile)
        for hosts in csvReader:
            cmd = subprocess.call(["ping", "-n", "1", hosts[0]], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            if cmd == 0:
                <The live hosts will need to go to the csv>
            else:
                <leave the dead hosts out of the csv>

            with open("liveHosts.csv", "w", newline="") as new_csv:
                csvWriter = csv.writer(new_csv, dialect="excel")
                for line in csvWriter:
                    csvWriter.writerows(line)
readCsv()
```

Comment: Note: you can [edit] your question to add stuff, instead of commenting.

Comment: Yes, but the write block is broken as well

Comment: Touche, and thanks for editing my function. Blorgbeard

Comment: How so? Is it only my spacing? @Mars

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want your output to look like?

Comment: Does your solution produce any errors?

Comment: Where is the expected csv file format?

Comment: Hey @Mars not sure if this is what you are asking for but, I would simply like to iterate through a list of IP addresses and if the IP returns a code 0 (it's up) to then write to a csv file.

Comment: @wwii the error I get is csvWriter is not an iterable object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stream can be opened to the output file using the same context manager used for the input one containing the list of hosts.

Then A CSV writer for the stream created. 
On the condition that the subprocess returned successfully, you can write a row to the CSV file.

```
with open("random.csv", "r") as allhosts, \
    open("liveHosts.csv", "w", newline="") as livehosts:
    csvReader = csv.reader(allhosts)
    csvWriter = csv.writer(livehosts, dialect="excel")

    for host in csvReader:
        cmd = subprocess.call(["ping", "-n", "1", host[0]], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        if cmd == 0:
            csvWriter.writerow(host)
```